# How to ensure the date string is in ISO 8061 format in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, api, express

I have to understand whether the given string is in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

I was tetsting using the following code snippet:

```
const isValidDate = (new Date(timestamp)).getTime() > 0;
```

However, in this case, "2015-06-22T13:17:21+0000" will be also valid.

I want to ensure only the day part is present in  `YYYY-MM-DD`.

What would be a neat concise way to determine this in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could do a regex test on the input string:

```js
var input = "2015-06-22";
if (/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/.test(input)) {
    console.log("MATCH");
}
```

If your requirement really be that the timestamp be precisely at midnight, you could also check the hours, minutes, and seconds components:

```js
var date = new Date();
date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
if (date.getHours() == 0 && date.getMinutes() == 0 &&
    date.getSeconds() == 0) {
    console.log("Date is at midnight");
}
```